# Find the solutions of: $\sin x+\cos x=\sin^2 x+0.5\sin{2x}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Find the solutions of: $\sin x+\cos x=\sin ^2 x+0.5\sin{(2x)}$

How can I find the solutions ?

Comment: Do you mean this equality? $$\sin^2x+\frac12\sin(2x)=\sin^2x+\sin x\cos x=\sin x(\sin x+\cos x)$$

Comment: The equation as written is wrong: Inserting $x=0$ gives $1=0$.

Comment: @celtschk, the question has been edited

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your equation, as you wrote it, is not true for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, nor even for most of them. Consider $x=0$, in which case the left hand side evaluates to $1$ and the right hand side equals $0$.

---

We can still find what values of $x$, if any, satisfy your equation.

Recall that

$$\sin (2x) = 2\sin x \cos x$$

Substitute this into your equation, to get

$$\sin x+\cos x=\sin ^2 x+ (0.5 \cdot 2)(\sin x \cos x)$$

$$\sin x+\cos x=\sin ^2 x+ \sin x \cos x $$

$$\sin x+\cos x= (\sin x)(\sin x + \cos x)$$

This equation is true when either

$$\sin x = 1$$

or

$$\sin x + \cos x = 0$$

The first condition occurs when $x=2\pi n + \frac{\pi}{2}$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. The second condition holds whenever $x= \pi n - \frac{\pi}{4}$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.